# The response has JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token \'?\'

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

Here is the response received from a `fetch` in react native 0.59.

```
'response in signup: ', { type: 'default',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   status: 200,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   ok: true,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   statusText: undefined,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   headers:
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:    { map:
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:       { connection: 'keep-alive',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         date: 'Sat, 27 Apr 2019 18:06:55 GMT',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         etag: 'W/"3c-2VCbAGm2oGWFDvRizej10F1Ythw"',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         'content-length': '60',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         'x-auth-token': 'ok to proceed',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         'x-powered-by': 'Express' } },
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   url: 'http://192.168.2.133:3000/api/users/signup',
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   _bodyInit:
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:    { _data:
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:       { size: 60,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         offset: 0,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         blobId: 'd0e4ba3e-2b4a-447e-9344-a81c4ae86c17' } },
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:   _bodyBlob:
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:    { _data:
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:       { size: 60,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         offset: 0,
04-27 11:06:47.426 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS:         blobId: 'd0e4ba3e-2b4a-447e-9344-a81c4ae86c17' } } }
04-27 11:06:47.507 31991 32031 I ReactNativeJS: 'error signing up: ', 'JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token \'?\''
```

What puzzles me is the error: `'JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token \'?\'`.
Here is the fetch in app:

```
let obj = JSON.stringify({
            _device_id: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
            cell: cell,
            cell_country_code: cell_country_code,
            name: username,
            corp_name: corp_name,
          });
          console.log("obj : ", obj);
          let res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
            },
              body: obj,
            });
```

This response is from the Nodejs 10.15 server and the data body returned is just empty. Only a header was set.

```
res.set("x-auth-token", "ok to proceed");
return res.status(200).send('Vcode sent out successfully');
```

Shall I remove `'Accept' : 'application/json'` from `fetch body`?  Where is the JSON.parser coming from and what caused the error?

Comment: If I understand the scenario correctly, you've a RN app from which you've made a POST call to your express server. And the first code-block above, shows the response of the POST call from the server. Maybe you can see if the handler of your POST endpoint is sending the expected payload. Also you can try POSTing the same data through POSTMAN or curl to verify and reproduce the same.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The express server returns messages. There is no data returned.

Comment: Yeah! Just check out response using other tools to make a POST request as suggested. Or it'd be great if you could also update the above question with the POST handler in your server.

Comment: The JSON.parser error disappears after adding `application/text, */*` to header accept

Comment: Good that this works. But this doesn't seem like the right solution. I'd recommend to have a look at the handler for your POST endpoint and check for the correctness there first.